# No java classes in downloaded Selenium jar

Tags: java, selenium, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to upgrade to Selenum 4.0.0-alpha-6 (same issue happens also with version 3.141.59) which seems to be available in [Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java). I tried first to add this dependency to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>            
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-alpha-6</version>
</dependency>
```

The version appears red in IntelliJ which for some reason sees 3.12.0 as the last available version. I know what version IntelliJ sees because I can hit CTRL-space inside the <version> tag.

Running `mvn install` also complains that the version is not available. So my first question is why do Intellij and Maven not see the latest versions of Selenium?

I reverted to downloading the jar file directly from mvnrepository (that is from [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-java/4.0.0-alpha-6/selenium-java-4.0.0-alpha-6.jar)) and adding it to my local repository as follows:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=selenium-java-4.0.0-alpha-6.jar 
-DgroupId=org.seleniumhq.selenium -DartifactId=selenium-java 
-Dversion=4.0.0-alpha-6 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

The jar appears now in my local repo, the Maven dependency does not appear red anymore, but all Selenium-related references in my project appear red. Examining the downloaded jar file reveals that it contains no Java classes:

```
C:\Development\Java\Selenium>jar tf selenium-java-4.0.0-alpha-6.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/versions/9/
META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Update: I have added [a small project in GitHub](https://github.com/yschondorf/pomTest) that demonstrates the problem. The pom just has the Selenium dependency.
Just running mvn install results in the error below. So this is not just a problem with IntelliJ:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project MySeleniumProject: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.my:MySeleniumProject:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:3.141.59 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ja
va:jar:3.141.59: Could not transfer artifact org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:pom:3.141.59 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to
 transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-java/3.141.59/selenium-java-3.141.59.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhras
e:HTTPS Required.
```

Comment: In IntelliJ try right clicking on your pom, then select `Maven -> Reload project`, then again select  `Maven -> Download Sources and documentation`. Latest IntelliJ seems having problems with autoupdating dependencies sometimes

Comment: @JockX this is not just a problem with IntelliJ. See the update that I have added. The problem of the missing dependency can be reproduced just by running mvn install.

Comment: I think your project is correct and problem is with maven configuration. Use commandline to see what maven version you have? `maven -v`. Try use `mvn dependency:resolve` on the project - from command line

Comment: The problem is indeed resolved by upgrading maven! I had Maven 3.0.5, and uprading to 3.6.3 resolved the dependency successfully. @Victor1125 if you post your comment as an answer I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved by upgrading maven. I had Maven 3.0.5, and uprading to 3.6.3 resolved the dependency successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try use stable older version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

Check also, if you have other errors in pom, and have proper java version

Comment: As I said in the original description, @Victor1125 : "same issue happens also with version 3.141.59". See also the update that I've added. You can download the project, run mvn install and the problem reproduces with 3.141.59.

Answer (score 0):

I think your project is correct and problem is with maven configuration. Use commandline to see what maven version you have? maven -v. Try use mvn dependency:resolve on the project - from command line